# Localization not working correctly - Language shown

Tags: c#, xaml, localization, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have one 'issue' that is driving me crazy. I must be doing or not doing something.

Using C# a Universal project. I developed an App with support for 3 languages. English, Spanish and Polish.

I followed these steps:

1. Created the folder "strings" with the different subfolders for each language "en", "es", "pl". And the resources.resw inside with the different texts.
2. In the Manifest set up as default language "en".
3. I checked that in the manifest I have the line Language="x-generate".

The thing is that when i Debug the application in my laptop or my Mobile (ARM) it runs correctly. (in visual studio i debug and it works)

The device is in English the app runs in English, the device is in Spanish the app runs in Spanish, etc.

But when i publish the Application in the Store and i install it in some device form the store it always runs in English.

I reviewed the devices where i install it from the Store, and English is not anywhere in the configuration.

Am i missing some step? do you know what can i review?

Thanks in advance,
Kind regards,

Comment: Just tried today again. 1. Run the project locally in my computer, changed the language and the application changes language correctly. 2. downloaded the application from the store, always in English.

Comment: Trying different things with package flights to see... no results by now.

Answer (score 2):

> But when I publish the Application in the Store and I install it in some device form the store it always runs in English.

If you want to let your Application runs in **Spanish** or **Polish** for the properties which are pointing to the resources files, you will have two ways.

The first way is set the **Spanish** or **Polish** language as the **default language** in your device, so please make sure that the devices who have downloaded your app have installed the **Spanish** or **Polish** language package and have set the **Spanish** or **Polish** language as the **default language**, otherwise it will show your App in English.

The second way is to use the [primaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh972398) to change the Language which you want to show for your app, in this way you may meet the question about the language works in the Visual Studio but does not work when uploading to the store, for the detailed information about how to solve it, please check my reply in here:
[UWP: Resource file for languages is not deployed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107907/uwp-resource-file-for-languages-is-not-deployed-correctly) .

Thanks.