# Why application from the Store is not localized?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10-universal

When running from Visual Stidio, my application is localized properly. But when downloaded from Windows Store, it runs only in English. Meanwhile in the Windows store it is indicated that application is supporting several languages.

I guess that localization is made properly, because when running it compiled directly from Visual Studio, everything is Ok.
But why this application, downloaded from the Store, behaves like it is not localized at all?

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064530/localization-not-working-correctly-language-shown

Comment: Also, device-specific optimization could be at play: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107907/uwp-resource-file-for-languages-is-not-deployed-correctly

Comment: Thank you very much for your links! Seems they give very useful information to understand what happens here.